# HttpServletResponse bean injected into bean in mvc

Tags: java, spring

In my spring-mvc project I have the following config:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig{
   @Bean
   SomeBean someBean(HttpServletResponse response){
      ... set response into new bean instance...
   }
}
```

*SomeBean* is got created only once, but response not.
Response has got *request* scope therefore we have classic *Narrow scope bean problem*.

But, in fact, SomeBean has got correct response field throughout mvc-app life(during multiple requests and responses, coming from a user.)

So, this field must have updated restlessly, but how can it be, taking into account SomeBean created only once!?

So, my question is how it is possible to have mutable response field ?

Comment: Apart from the fact you shouldn't do this (IMHO). The `HttpServletResponse ` is injected as a proxy and when needed the current active `HttpServletResponse` is obtain on the fly. That is the one bound to the current executing thread (it is basically request scoped). This has to be done else your application wouldn't even start as at the moment of starting there isn't an active `HttpServletResponse`.

Comment: @M.Deinum i need to alter cookies in response, based on logic, conducted in SomeBean. So, i must inject response in it.

Comment: Then create a method that takes the `HttpServletResponse` instead of relying it to be set in a scoped variable. This is more clear and direct now it is hidden and you possibly tie your whole application to the web (depending on where you call that functionality in `SomeBean`).

Comment: @M.Deinum if i create a method, that returns response won't it indicate web-related thing ?
response itself is only related to web

Comment: If you use that class `SomeBean` from a a repository or a service (which is doable right now because you are injecting things) your application is now fully tied to the web. Whereas if you use it as a method signature you would probably think twice in using this class from a service and only use it in the appropriate layer.